# MFMailComposeViewController does not work when customizing font with UIAppearance proxy

Tags: iphone, ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, uiappearance

MFMailComposeViewController is presented and working fine when I do not customize the fonts in my app. But when I do, 50% of the time it got presented and call directly his delegate with `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:` with the result `MFMailComposeResultCancelled` exactly like if the user just try to closed it.

And also trigger this error in the console:

```
_serviceViewControllerReady:error: Error Domain=XPCObjectsErrorDomain Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (XPCObjectsErrorDomain error 2.)"
```

Looks like the mail composer does not like the appearance proxy, but the problem is that it's not event possible de disable the appearance proxy for it.

For every navigation bar in my application, I have a custom design. To achieve this I used the appearence proxy like this:

```
UIImage *navBarBackground = [UIImage stretchableHorizontalImageNamed:@"navbar-background"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBarBackground forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar-shadow"]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
    UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.965f green:0.635f blue:0.647f alpha:1.f],
    UITextAttributeFont : [UIFont brothersBoldFontOfSize:20.f],
    UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor blackColor],
    UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)]
}];

UIBarButtonItem *navBarButtonItemAppearance = [UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil];
[navBarButtonItemAppearance setTitleTextAttributes:@{
    UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.478f green:0.008f blue:0.023f alpha:1.f],
    UITextAttributeFont : [UIFont brothersBoldFontOfSize:17.f],
    UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.f alpha:0.3f],
    UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)]
} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I removed some background customization for the popover with the folowing:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIPopoverController class], nil] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

It's working fine for the popover. But impossible to remove it for the mail composer, even when I use "when contained in" MFMailComposeViewController and set it to `nil` it's still here.

I also try to subclass it or set a system font but that does not change anything. He got presented, print the error, call his delegate and get dismissed. I just saw that when it's working, the font is not applied by the system and when it's not it got presented with the custom font like below.

[image]

Comment: Hey, have you got the solution for this? Because I am facing the same problem and also googling since couple of days. If you've been successful in solving this, please let me know... :)

Comment: I have got the solution.... if you have set custom fonts with `UINavigationBar` in any of your classes, then it will affect to `MFMailComposeViewController`. So, you remove the custom Navigationbar font from all the classes, it will work fine. I think this is the only solution. You might have set custom fonts with Navigationbar... :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that custom fonts take too long to load and it triggers a time-out from the wait-fences.

See: [MFMailComposeViewController throws a viewServiceDidTerminateWithError and then exits when using a custom title font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624151/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-throws-a-viewservicedidterminatewitherror-and-then-e)

Comment: I saw this link too, but there is no solution. The workaround code doen't work (on iOS 6).